# C# DllImport issue calling C++ library

Tags: interop, marshalling, dllimport

I need to call a C++ library from a C# program, I have a method whose signature looks like:

```
int __stdcall meythodName(const char *c, struct TheirStruct[] s1, struct TheirStruct[] s2)
```

all parameters are output parameters.

I'm trying to call this method like this:

```
[DllImport("theirlib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
extern static int meythodName(ref string c, ref TheirStruct[] s1, ref TheirStruct[] s2);
```

With TheirStruct being like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = 13)]
public class TheirStruct
{
   public int i;  
   public int j;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
   public string s;
}
```

TheirStruct (PACKED and 13 byte in size) is described in dll manual as:

```
#define LEN 5
#define SIZE 50

struct TheirStruct 
{
    char c[LEN]; 
    int i;                   
    int j;                   
};
```

When I try to call this method my application simply terminates without giving me an error code, can you give me some explanations about this issue?

Comment: Not "ref string s" - it should be "string" if it is read-only, or preallocated StringBuilder if TheirMethods writes to it (of course you can use IntPtrs and deal with all conversions those things manually). I actually don't know how to pass TheirStruct[] but "ref" seems wrong to me. I woudl rather use IntPtr in this case and allocate/marshal everything myself).

Comment: Nope it doesn't work either, I think the master problem is with TheirStruct, can you explain what you mean by using "IntPtr"?

Comment: Remove the *ref* keywords in the declaration, strings and arrays are already passed by reference.  And do make the struct look the same, the order of the fields is not arbitrary.

Comment: I've removed all "ref" but now I get a "Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown." when executing this method

Comment: I changed to:
    
    [DllImport("theirlib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    extern static int methodName(String c, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] TheirStruct[] s1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] TheirStruct[] s2);

and 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class TheirStruct
{
   public int i;  
   public int j;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
   public char[] s;
}

still no good I get "System.ExecutionEngineException"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found!!!

I just needed to change "class" to "struct" in TheirStruct declaration, remove di "ref" keyword in method invocation and set the [In]/[Out] accordingly.

Quite simple, hope this can be of any help!!